# Python EXEC show error: name is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, exec

I used exec with selenium to run as below,

```
from selenium import webdriver
search_method = 'find_element_by_class_name'
search_word = 'keyword'
exec("elem_search_word = driver." + search_method + "('" + search_word + "')")
elem_search_word.send_keys('python'))
```

but I got error, what can I do?

```
elem_search_word.send_keys(str(args.search))
NameError: name 'elem_search_word' is not defined
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `exec`? Also let us know whether this is your *actual* code or *simplified*. If it is simplified code - share exact code you uses as above code should work as expected

Comment: There is that import.

Comment: The search_method and search_word is from property file `find_element_by_class_name = keyword`, so I have to use EXEC. This is simplified code, I am not sure why it doesn't work, anything else I should careof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue, but IMHO you should avoid using `exec()` in this case. Try below instead:

```
search_method = 'class name'
search_word = 'keyword'
elem_search_word = driver.find_element(search_method, search_word)
elem_search_word.send_keys('python')
```

If you want to search by `id`, `xpath`, `css`... just set `search_method` with appropriate value

Alternatively:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

search_method = By.CLASS_NAME
search_word = 'keyword'
elem_search_word = driver.find_element(search_method, search_word)
elem_search_word.send_keys('python')
```

Comment: I tried `elem_search_word = driver.find_element('find_element_by_class_name', 'keyword') ` and I got error is `'value': value})['value']`

Comment: Do not pass `'find_element_by_class_name'`, use `"class name"`, `"id"`, `"name"`, `"xpath"`, etc: `driver.find_element('class name', 'keyword')`. You can also import [By class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) and use `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'keyword')`

Comment: Well, I change property to `class name = keyword`, now it works! Thanks a lot!